# Laravel is there a way to dehash the IDs of data in URL before accessing the route?

Tags: php, laravel, hashids

I'm using the package `hashids\hashids` to hash the ID of data sent through the URL (e.g .../post/bsdfs/edit, the 'bsdfs' is the encoded value). I followed [Stuart Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860371/use-hashids-library-to-hash-ids-on-laravel-eloquent-collection)'s accessor method to do so. Below is how I do it:

```php
use Hashids\Hashids;

class Post extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['hashid'];

    public function getHashidAttribute() {
        $hashid = new Hashids(config('hash.keyword'));

        return $hashid->encode($this->attributes['id']);
    }
}
```

Before hashing the IDs I am getting `post/2/edit`. After the hashing process, I'm getting `post/bsdfs/edit`, which is fine to me.

The problem occurs when redirecting to the encoded route. This is how my route looks like:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
    
Route::get('post/{post}/edit', 'PostController@edit')->name('post.edit');
```

After redirecting, I get a 404 error. This is what the controller accepts:

```php
Use App\Models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller {
    //PS: I don't actually know what this method is called...
    public function edit(Post $post) {
        return view('post.edit')->with(compact('post'));
    }
}
```

I know that if I'm doing this method, Laravel is searching for an ID of 'bsdfs', which does not exist in the database. What it should do is decode the hash and get the ID. Is there a way to do it WITHOUT doing this:

```php
public function edit($id) {
    $hashid = new Hashids(config('hash.keyword'));
    $id= $hashid->decode($id);

    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('post.edit')->with(compact('post'));
}
```

As you can see, my goal here is to reduce the number of lines while still maintaining the data ID in the URL to be encoded. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of [Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic).

So your model should have something like this:

```php
/**
 * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    $hashid = new Hashids(config('hash.keyword'));

    return $this->findOrFail($hashid->decode($value)[0]);
}
```

So you can then have your controller like nothing happend:

```php
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    return view('post.edit')->with(compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: The data returned is in the form of array. Is this because of hashids\hashids?

Comment: What of all 3 possible points are return as array ? `$hashid->decode($value)`, ` return $this->findOrFail(...)` or ` return view('post.edit')->with(compact('post'));` ? Share here the error you are now having please...

Comment: I dd($hashid->decode($value));, it returns array : 1 [ [0] => 1 ].. I didnt receive an error, but the eloquent is empty

Comment: I never used the library you are using, I saw the [documentation](https://github.com/vinkla/hashids) on github and I see that `decode()` will always return an array with 1 or more elements. So see my updated answer and try it.

Comment: I see, so it is the limitation of the library itself. Ok thanks alot for your help! I'll mark this as the right answer.

Comment: Is it better to call an attribute that would return the hashed id, or save it to the database?